# Paperclip Gem - undefined method '_image_post_process_callbacks'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have an application on Heroku that uses the Paperclip gem that recently had some issues - and I'm not 100% sure on what it was that caused it. I have the application working locally (including the image upload) - but I get an 'Application Error' page on the heroku url, and when I try to access the heroku console with heroku run rails c it gets an error of:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in 'method_missing': undefined method '_image_post_process_callbacks' for #<Class:0x007f8aaf5d2fa0> (NoMethodError)
```

A little background on the issue - another developer was working on creating an image upload model - which was named 'Images' - which I think caused problems with Paperclip, and wouldn't allow me to run a Rails migration. When I tried it said there was an issue with the 'Images' table, so after finding a similar situation online, I commented out the body of the 'def change' within the create_images migration - which now looks like so:

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
# create_table :images do |t|
# t.attachment :file
# end
end
end
```

I then ran another migration - started my server locally and everything was working. I then pushed my changes to heroku, did a rake db:migrate for good luck - and the heroku url is still showing 'Application Error'

If anyone has any idea of possible causes of these issues, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading!

**EDIT**

After running `heroku run rails c` I get this output.

`Running rails c on independentskiermag... up, run.7049
Routing about
Routing terms-of-service
Routing privacy-policy
Routing contact
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in 'method_missing': undefined method '_image_post_process_callbacks' for #<Class:0x007f9ff5864330> (NoMethodError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:785:in 'get_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:647:in 'set_callback'
    from (eval):2:in 'before_image_post_process'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.2/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:67:in 'create_validating_before_filter'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.2/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:60:in 'block in validate_before_processing'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.2/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:58:in 'each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.2/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:58:in 'validate_before_processing'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.2/lib/paperclip/validators/attachment_content_type_validator.rb:84:in 'validates_attachment_content_type'
    from /app/app/models/image.rb:4:in '<class:Image>'
    from /app/app/models/image.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in 'require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in 'depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in 'require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in 'block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in 'each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in 'block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in 'each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in 'eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in 'eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in 'each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in 'block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in 'block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in 'block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in 'block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in 'each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in 'block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in 'each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in 'each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in 'tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 'run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in 'initialize!'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in 'require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in 'require_application_and_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in 'console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in 'run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in '<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in 'require'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in '<main>'`

Comment: Did your other developer also push to heroku and run a migration?

Comment: yeah - there was a migration run on heroku

Comment: The CreateImages migration, I assume? What was the issue with the Images table?

Comment: yes, is there a way to revert that? and - would that be causing this error anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace. It looks like there's something wrong with your image model. Can you also post the `app/models/image.rb` and your `config/routes.rb` file? Those messages at the top like `Routing contact` make me curious also.

Comment: it was an error in the image.rb! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Cool man, glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you need to undo a migration on Heroku, you will need to un-comment out the body of your migration, push to Heroku, then run `heroku run rake db:rollback` in order to undo it and get your application working again in the interim.

If you are still having trouble, post the errors and any relevant code in your post.

Comment: I un-commented out the body of the migration, pushed to heroku, ran `heroku run rake db:rollback STEP=2` (there were two migrations that I wanted to go back)... but then how do I now run the migration? Won't it run the recent migration files again?

Comment: Does your application work now, or is there something else going on?

If you want to run one specific migration you can do `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=[migration]`, where `[migration]` is the number of the specific migration from `rake db:migrate:status`. But I have to wonder if there's something else going on with your code that is going to prevent you from having any luck with that.

Comment: no - it still wasn't working... I was thinking the `create_images.rb` migration could have caused issues with paperclip?

Comment: It's possible but unlikely. The migration that you showed is supposed to create a table named 'images' and add a few columns to it [(your given column name, then :file_name, :content_type, :file_size, :updated_at to be exact)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/72b4603a12774286ccceee8779de439406b85b66/lib/paperclip/schema.rb#L54), and that should work regardless. My guess is there's something further going on in your code. If you can duplicate the error, can you update your post and add the full stack trace to it?